# Key height in custom input method (keyboard)

Tags: android, input, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I have included a slightly modified version of the Gingerbread keyboard in my Android app. This works for most devices, but few users report display problems.

As a simplified example, I used the code from [Gingerbread keyboard on Github](https://github.com/g1011999/Gingerbread-Keyboard). I could reproduce the problem there as well:

One problem can be seen in the GenyMotion Emulator (Nexus 7, Android 4.1.1, API 16, 1280x800) where the keyboard compiled by myself looks like

[image: Wrong keyboard row height]

Whereas installing the Gingerbread keyboard from Play Store (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moo.android.inputmethod.latin.free&hl=de) seems to be correct:

[image: Correct keyboard row height]

The keyboard row height is defined as

```
<Keyboard
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyWidth="10%p"
    android:horizontalGap="0px"
    android:verticalGap="@dimen/key_bottom_gap"
    android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height"
>
```

with

```
<dimen name="key_height">0.290in</dimen>
```

for all screen sizes (there is no values-hdpi or similar, only values folder).

Now I was wondering what could cause this behavior? Why could "my" keyboard be different from the Play store version? Of course I cannot guarantee it's exactly the same code, but as the Gingerbread keyboard code from AOSP looks the same, I guess it's more a problem with my toolchain or manifest?

I tried with Android SDK level 17 and SDK level 8 with same results. Any further ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using a different unit of measurement? Like dpi. Also, not sure how you are doing this really, but if it has anything to do with drawables have you checked your different screen density drawables?

Comment: I wouldn't suspect that I have to modify the code because this is Android OS (2.3) production code!

Comment: But you aren't using it on an Android 2.3 device... if you don't modify any code, you aren't going to change any behavior :)

Comment: as described above, it seems to be a problem in my build chain, because the app from the Play store which (very likely) uses the same code is ok.

Comment: Have you tried playing with the code at all though? To assume that the code has remained the same since 2.3 is a pretty bold assumption, considering how much things have changed (especially including resolutions) since 2.3. It very well may be your build configuration, but it is far easier to start by tweaking code. Not like it can make it worse, and is super easy to revert from :P

Comment: The app in the Play store was released in April 2011, this is basically when everybody had Android 2.3 or earlier (3.0 was released just a few weeks earlier).

Comment: ... but that isn't the case anymore is what I am saying. The device you are talking about is a newer device with a newer version of Android. You are using a 3 year old keyboard on a newer device and hoping that it works without any modification. I am sure the keyboard you have likely works just fine on 3 year old devices running ~3.0 android on smaller resolutions (as it was intended to)

Comment: it DOES run on the new emulator (see second screenshot). It just doesn't run when I build it by myself. I certainly could find code that might work on this device, but it's unlikely that this will work on the thousands other devices which my app runs on.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height"` in your Keyboard definition, try using something like `android:keyHeight="6%p"` instead. You'll probably need to play around with the percentage to get it to look right.

Comment: The root cause of your problem is that you're using a fixed height for all screen heights. If you want to use defined dimensions, you'll have to add dimen definitions in the various alternate values folders (such as values-sw600dp, values-sw720dp-land, etc.). In the larger folders, you'll want larger values for your definitions. Personally, I find that approach a bit tedious and usually do keyboard sizes with percentages.

Comment: please also see the discussion in the comments to the question.

Comment: I agree with zgc7009. You're using the keyboard from Gingerbread, but not all of Gingerbread. It's possible that this same code functions differently on devices running the old firmware as it does on newer devices.

Comment: It's also very unlikely that the 3rd party version of the Gingerbread keyboard in the Play Store is actually running the same code that you've downloaded.